Blazor HttpClient service Error on page reload
I have an api https://localhost:7293/ everything works fine however consuming the api using httpclient on blazor wasm or blazor app wasm or auto render  is a nightmare works on load but crashes on reload.
Tried swapping HttpClient on all kind of ways still got the errors.
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IDashboardService, DashboardService>(
         api => api.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7293/"));

or
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

or
builder.Services.AddScoped(
       sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7293/") });

Note: This is in dotnet 8 Version="8.0.6"

What errors do you see?  "It crashes" isn't much help.

We have official document for blazor app call external web API. It also includes several samples.
Here's my test in the blazor auto API(an app includes a blazorapp and a blazorapp.Client).
Fisrtly, in my Client app, I have the Counter.raozr by default. I added @rendermode InteractiveAuto to set render mode InteractiveAuto in this component. It requires me to add builder.Services.AddHttpClient(); in the Program.cs of the blazorapp instead of the blazorapp.Client. Then in the component, I added codes below which worked well.
@inject HttpClient Http
@rendermode InteractiveAuto

<button @onclick="GetTodoItems">call API</button>

@code {
    private async Task GetTodoItems()
    {
        var apiResult = await Http.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:7087/api/Hello");
    }
}

Scenario 2 for @rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly.
This time we need to add codes below into Program.cs of the blazorapp.Client. We don't need the configuration in blazorapp project.
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7087") });

In the meantime, since it's sent from the client app we need to add CORS policy into the external WEB API project. Otherwise we will get error like System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: TypeError: Failed to fetch  ---> TypeError: Failed to fetch in blazor app.
